# Battery indicates 0 after fully charged and hibernated on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: suspend, power-management, battery, 19.10, hibernate

I'm using Ubuntu 19.10 eoan on my Lenovo ThinkPad P1 Gen 2, and I noticed on several occasions that after suspending my computer with Window + L, unplugging my computer (when the battery is at 100%), and then opening the computer lid to login after 30 minutes, the battery indicator says it is at 0, and that shutdown is imminent. Then it shuts down before I have the chance to plug in my power cable. When I plug it in and reboot the machine, the battery immediately says 90+%, 6-7 minutes to full charge. This has happened 2 or 3 times so far. I think this behavior is using both Intel and NVIDIA graphics drivers. I checked power statistics and it says it has 0% prediction accuracy sometimes. I'm not sure why. How can I look into this matter further and report back to the community? Is there anything I can do to prevent this from happening?

As a workaround, I'm pretty fortunate to commit most things to version control on a regular basis, Firefox boots up my tabs, and Startup Applications are generally configured to my liking. I can also try to plug in the computer before opening the laptop lid.